# The reactive variable is not displaying the right output in Svelte

Tags: svelte, string-concatenation, reactive

I think it's pretty obvious what this code should do, but the output is not as I expected it to be.

```
<script>
  let firstName = "first";
  let lastName = "last";
  let myColor = "orange";

  $: fullName = "${firstName} ${lastName}";
  $: console.log(myColor);
</script>

<main>
  <p>{fullName} - and he has a nice {myColor} shirt</p>
  <input type="text" bind:value={firstName} />
  <input type="text" bind:value={lastName} />
  <input type="text" bind:value={myColor} />
</main>
```

Here is the output (without the input slots):

```
${firstName} ${lastName} - and he has a nice orange shirt
```

I don't know why it didn't replace the `fullName` with the concat vars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use backticks ([template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)) to concatenate strings like that. This works:

```js
$: fullName = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
```

Comment: I'm using VSCode and once I save my project. They autoformat it to what you see, I'm not sure if that's an extension I have or something..

Comment: Oh no, you're right. I was confusing the backstick ` with the apostrophy '   ..Thank god, you mentioned the word, I appreciate your response!